# C - converting to 2s complement

Tags: c, twos-complement

I've decided to do it this way

- flip numbers 0=1, 1=0
- add 1 to LSB
- if carry, loop until array[i]==0

But I'm stuck on the last point; how can I say that in a conditional loop?

Comment: Why do you need to convert something to 2s compliment representation? I believe everything is usually stored in that way already.

Comment: Please, clarify what you are talking about. At this time it is hard to make sense of your question. What are you "converting to 2s complement" and why?

Comment: array[] contains the binary for say 7 (1110), -7 is stored in array1[] = 1001

Comment: You say that you are stuck on the last point. That implies that you have working code for the first two points. Can you post that code please?

Comment: And is this homework? If so, use the homework tag. If not, why not just store the number as an integer instead of an array with each element representing one bit?

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about extended arithmetic. Most processors have carry-out and overflow results from every addition operation, but C does not provide access to them.

Your problem is that numbers get longer as they get bigger. If you're at the last bit you have, and you need to carry out, you need another bit! That means you need to reallocate the array of bits (if you are using an array).

Of course, a more practical solution is to use native integers rather than individual bits, since your processor already handles two's-complement quite nicely. Then, you know that adding one results in a carry-out if the original number is equal to `(unsigned) -1`. The fundamental problem remains; if you need to carry out of the last `unsigned` you need to allocate another.

Answer (score 0):

So you you store your number as an array of ints, which represent bits.
In the code example you attached you forgot to increment the *i* variable, and to check if it exceeded the size of your array.

You could write something like this (I assume the size of the array is **5**):

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (array1[i] == 1)
        array1[i] = 0;
    else // we found a 0
        array1[i] = 1;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're doing, but maybe this will help:

```
#define countof(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))

// an 8-bit number
int byte[8] = {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}; // 1 = on, 0 = off

// flip all bits
for (size_t i = 0; i < countof(byte); ++i)
{
    byte[i] = !byte[i];
}

// add one
for (size_t i = 0; i < countof(byte); ++i)
{
    if (byte[i]) // if on
    {
        byte[i] = 0; // "add 1, reset to zero", and carry (no break)
    }
    else // if off
    {
        byte[i] = 1; // turn on
        break; // nothing to carry, stop adding
    }

}
```

(I don't know how to push you in the right direction without just explaining the code, sorry. I think you're close enough this is still helpful.)

You see, when you add one, if the bit is already one, reset it to zero, and continue along the bits. If the bit is zero, set it to one, then break out of the loop. (Nothing to carry, so we're done adding.)

Hope that helps. By the way, you'll note the bits are being stored "backwards" in the code above. The LSB is at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2's complement in a much easier way like bellow:

- go unchanged till you find an 1.
- just after getting the first 1, flip the next coming 0's to 1 and 1's to Zeros and continue doing this. if the  MSB becomes 0, it means overflow occurred.

you can check the validity of the algorithm by yourself. and the implementation should be like bellow:

```
// an 8-bit number
int number[8] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0};
int i;
bool gotFirstOne = false;

// flip bits after you first encountered an 1
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
   if(gotFirstOne == false){
       if(number[i] == 1) {
           gotFirstOne = true;
       }
   }
   else {
       number[i] = !number[i];
   }

}

if(number[7] == 0) {
    printf("Overflow occurred");
}
```

Cheers!!!!

Answer (score 0):

My Answer to 2's complement, remember this is for 12 bit complement, you can change mask or integer type as per your requirement. This is working perfectly, also can do it using a Macro.

```
int twos_compliment(unsigned short a)
{
    int result;
    result = 0x0FFF&a;
    result = (((result&0x800)?(0<<11):(1<<11))|((result&0x400)?(0<<10):(1<<10))
            |((result&0x200)?(0<<9):(1<<9))|((result&0x100)?(0<<8):(1<<8))
            |((result&0x080)?(0<<7):(1<<7))|((result&0x040)?(0<<6):(1<<6))
            |((result&0x020)?(0<<5):(1<<5))|((result&0x010)?(0<<4):(1<<4))
            |((result&0x008)?(0<<3):(1<<3))|((result&0x004)?(0<<2):(1<<2))
            |((result&0x002)?(0<<1):(1<<1))|((result&0x001)?0:1));
    return result=result+1;
}
```